# Beautiful Soup only extracting one tag when can see all the others in the html code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

Trying to understand how web scraping works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops"
result = requests.get(url)
doc = soup(result.text, "lxml")
items = doc.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4'})
for item in items:
    caption = item.find('div', {'class': 'caption'})
    price = item.find('h4', {'class': 'pull-right price'})
print(price.string)
```

However, when I run this all that returns is the final price from the website ($1799.00). Why does it skip all the other h4 tags and just return the last one?

Any help would be much appreciated!

If you need any more information please let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What happens?

You call the `print()` after you finally iterated over your results, thats why you only get the last one.

#### How to fix?

Put the `print()` into your loop

```
for item in items:
    caption = item.find('div', {'class': 'caption'})
    price = item.find('h4', {'class': 'pull-right price'})
    print(price.string)
```

#### Output

```
$295.99
$299.00
$299.00
$306.99
$321.94
$356.49
$364.46
$372.70
$379.94
$379.95
$391.48
$393.88
$399.00
$399.99
$404.23
$408.98
$409.63
$410.46
$410.66
$416.99
$433.30
$436.29
$436.29
$439.73
$454.62
$454.73
$457.38
$465.95
$468.56
$469.10
$484.23
$485.90
$487.80
$488.64
$488.78
$494.71
$497.17
$498.23
$520.99
$564.98
$577.99
$581.99
$609.99
$679.00
$679.00
$729.00
$739.99
$745.99
$799.00
$809.00
$899.00
$999.00
$1033.99
$1096.02
$1098.42
$1099.00
$1099.00
$1101.83
$1102.66
$1110.14
$1112.91
$1114.55
$1123.87
$1123.87
$1124.20
$1133.82
$1133.91
$1139.54
$1140.62
$1143.40
$1144.20
$1144.40
$1149.00
$1149.00
$1149.73
$1154.04
$1170.10
$1178.19
$1178.99
$1179.00
$1187.88
$1187.98
$1199.00
$1199.00
$1199.73
$1203.41
$1212.16
$1221.58
$1223.99
$1235.49
$1238.37
$1239.20
$1244.99
$1259.00
$1260.13
$1271.06
$1273.11
$1281.99
$1294.74
$1299.00
$1310.39
$1311.99
$1326.83
$1333.00
$1337.28
$1338.37
$1341.22
$1347.78
$1349.23
$1362.24
$1366.32
$1381.13
$1399.00
$1399.00
$1769.00
$1769.00
$1799.00
```

#### Example

Instead of just printing the results while iterating, store them structured in a list of dicts and print or save it after the for loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops"
result = requests.get(url)
doc = soup(result.text, "lxml")
items = doc.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4'})
data = []
for item in items:
    data.append({
        'caption' : item.a['title'],
        'price' : item.find('h4', {'class': 'pull-right price'}).string
    })
    
print(data)
```